# what does the cmpq instruction do?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I was reading the following definition for syscall:

```
.text
.globl syscall
.type   syscall,%function
.align 16
syscall:
    movq %rdi, %rax     /* Syscall number -> rax.  */
    movq %rsi, %rdi     /* shift arg1 - arg5.  */
    movq %rdx, %rsi
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    movq %r8, %r10
    movq %r9, %r8
    movq 8(%rsp),%r9    /* arg6 is on the stack.  */
    syscall         /* Do the system call.  */
    cmpq $-4095, %rax   /* Check %rax for error.  */
    jae __syscall_error     /* Branch forward if it failed.  */
    ret         /* Return to caller.  */

.size syscall,.-syscall
```

I saw it explained that the line `cmpq $-4095 %rax` determines whether %rax contains a value between -1 and -4095.  How does it do that?  What exactly does the cmpq instruction do?

Answer (score 26):

`cmpq $-4095, %rax` compares the 64-bit register %rax with the immediate value `-4095` - the value is sign-extended to 64-bits for the purposes of the comparison. i.e., `-4095` has the 64-bit 2's complement representation: `ffff ffff ffff f001`

`cmp` instructions set the flags register as it would for a `sub` (subtract) of the second operand from the first - 'second' and 'first' being reversed in AT&T syntax. In effect the flags are set according to the result of: `(RAX - (- 4095))` or `(RAX + 4095)`, being the same in 2's complement.

One of the flags set is the *carry* flag (CF), which is set on (unsigned) overflow. The `jae` instruction (jump-if-above-or-equal) is actually an 'alias' for `jnc` (jump-if-not-carry). In other words, the branch is taken if `(RAX + 4095)` does *not* carry. In 2's complement, this will be true for values of `RAX` in the range: `[-4095, -1]`. (Keeping in mind how 2's complement arithmetic wraps).

---

The instructions, including `cmp` and `jae` (or `j<cond>`) are described in: [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 2](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf).

The [E]FLAGS register (and what the arithmetic flags denote) are described in section 3.4.3 of [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf).