# Assembly: comparison returns just the opposite of expected result

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, x86-64

I have to code some sort of compiler and it works quite good, but I have a problem with the semantic of an "is-greater-than" expression.

As example I want to return the smallest argument:

```
func mymin(x y)
  cond
    x>y then return y; end;
  end;
  return x;
end;
```

Conditional-Statements should return -1 if they are true (otherwise 0). Therefore I copy 0 into the destination register (here it's %rax). If the left operand is greater I copy -1 into %rax (with the conditional move). The comparison between -1 and the result of the condition (`cmp $-1, %rax`) ensures a jump if it's true (-1 - -1 = 0).

But it's just the opposite. so

```
mymin(2,3) = 3
mymin(1,0) = 1
// ...
```

What's wrong?!

```
    .text

    .globl mymin
    .type mymin, @function
mymin:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    # calculate greater one between %rdi and %rsi to %rax (reg & reg)
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $-1, %r10
    cmpq %rdi, %rsi
    cmovgq %r10, %rax
    cmp $-1, %rax
    jz cond_1
    jmp cond_2
cond_1:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    ret
    jmp cond_2
cond_2:
    movq %rdi, %rax
    ret
```

Comment: This syntax (AT&T) is the opposite of Intel's own documentation (see [what does the cmpq instruction do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440403/what-does-the-cmpq-instruction-do)). Switch the registers in `cmovgq %r10, %rax`?

Comment: The registers should be switched in the `cmp` not the `cmov`.

Comment: @Jester: oops :) Yeah that's what I meant, in hindsight. Must've copied the wrong line.

Comment: So I got the AT&T syntax right first time ? :) If so, I'll remove my provisional comment from the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment (and @Jester's correction), if you find the opposite value gets stored, you may have mixed up "left" and "right' in the `cmpq` operation.

But.. here is another, shorter take: why use an intermediate flag at all?

```
.text

.globl mymin
.type mymin, @function

mymin:
    movq %rsi, %rax
    # calculate greater one between %rdi and %rsi to %rax (reg & reg)
    movq %rdi, %rax
    cmpq %rsi, %rdi
    cmovle %rsi, %rax
    ret
```

`rax` gets loaded with the first value `rsi`, and it's assumed this is the lesser value. Then, you compare `rdi` with `rsi`. If this is less or equal, write `rdi` into `rax` instead.

(**Disclaimer:** I don't like AT&T's odd syntax and so it's probable, nay, even *likely*, I made the same error as you. Untested.)