# Why Can't These Templatized Functions Take No Arguments?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, arguments, sfinae

I am trying to use a couple templatized functions for [Substitution Fail Is Not An Error(SFINAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). And I can do it like this:

```
template<typename R, typename S = decltype(declval<R>().test())> static true_type Test(R*);
template<typename R> static false_type Test(...);
```

But I'm not understanding how the argument makes this SNFIAE work. It seems like I should just be able to remove the arguments and the template selection would work the exact same way:

```
template<typename R, typename S = decltype(declval<R>().test())> static true_type Test();
template<typename R> static false_type Test();
```

But it does not, I get:

> Call of overloaded 'Test()' is ambiguous

What is it about these arguments that make this SFINAE work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example fails to compile, since there are two overloads of `Test` with identical signature, becasue defaulted template type arguments are not part of function signature. That is not allowed.

Your first example works in followign manner:

When type `R` does have a function `test` in it, both `Test` become valid overload candidates. However, ellipsis functions have lower rank than non-ellipsis ones, and thus compiler selects the first overload, returning `true_type`.

When R does not have `test` on it, the first overload is excluded from overload resolution set (SFINAE at works). You are left with only the second one, which returns `false_type`.

Comment: But beyond that, there is something special about these argument types that causes them to be evaluated in the correct order. I don't understand why the compiler prefers `R*` to `...`. Can you explain that?

Comment: @JonathanMee, will add to the answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee to put it simply, (...) is the least-preferred match to any argument list when performing overload resolution. This is by design and it's mandated in the standard. Coincidentally it's also the least-preferred way of implementing a function with variable arguments :-)

Comment: So I can always force compiler preference by using ellipsis as my second argument... interesting.

Comment: @RichardHodges But I still couldn't default the first parameter `int i = 0` and accept `...` as the second parameter. Why is that?

Comment: @JonathanMee it would still be ambiguous wouldn't it?

Comment: @JonathanMee, what is the full signature of both functions now?

Comment: @SergeyA `template<typename R, typename S = decltype(declval<R>().test())> static true_type Test(int i = 0);
template<typename R> static false_type Test(...);`

Comment: @RichardHodges it is... but if the `...` is always of lower priority, I'd like to think SFINAE would choose the first one. (it doesn't work.) Why not?

Comment: JonathanMee, move away from SFINAE for a sec, and try to understand overload resolution process first. When you have two function signatures, one having defaulted parameter, and another one having ellipsis (or no parameter for that matter!) all those overloads have equal rank. @RichardHodges was not exactly correct when he said that ellipsis always has lowest rank.

Comment: @JonathanMee added another answer which (hopefully) explains things fully. It took a while for this stuff to sink in to my head when I first encountered it...

Comment: @RichardHodges So I think what we're coming to is the `...` parameter is lower rank *than functions which require an argument* but equal rank to a function which doesn't require an argument. This seems reflected in my tests, but would it be too much for me to ask for a source?

Comment: @JonathanMee it's mentioned here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

Comment: @RichardHodges I see, Still nothing about why it doesn't work when no arguments are needed by the primary option. But I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: JonathanMee, this is because @RichardHodges didn't give the best link out there. The rules are here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution. (Look for `Best viable function`). They do not really mention ellipsis or non-ellipsis functions. Instead, they talk about argument conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered but maybe it's useful to go into a deeper explanation.

Hopefully this annotated program will make things clearer:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

// define the template function Test<R> if and only if the expression
// std::declval<R>().test()
// is a valid expression.
// in which case Test<R, decltype(std::declval<R>().test())>(0) will be preferrable to... (see after)
template<typename R, typename S = decltype(std::declval<R>().test())> 
  static std::true_type Test(R*);

// ...the template function Test<R>(...)
// because any function overload with specific arguments is preferred to this
template<typename R> static std::false_type Test(...);


struct foo
{
  void test();
};

struct bar
{
  // no test() method
//  void test();
};


// has_test<T> deduces the type that would have been returned from Test<T ... with possibly defaulted args here>(0)
// The actual Test<T>(0) will be the best candidate available
// For foo, it's Test<foo, decltype(std::declval<R>().test())>(foo*)
// which deduces to
// Test<foo, void>(foo*)
// because that's a better match than Test<foo>(...)
//
// for bar it's Test<bar>(...)
// because Test<bar, /*error deducing type*/>(bar*)
// is discarded as a candidate, due to SFNAE
//
template<class T>
constexpr bool has_test = decltype(Test<T>(0))::value;


int main()
{
  std::cout << has_test<foo> << std::endl;
  std::cout << has_test<bar> << std::endl;
}
```