# Only Move Iterator Once

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, initialization, iteration

I'm trying to find a way to improve [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36425799/2642059). Let's simplify the question to say: I want to partition the input container, lets call it `foo`, into a `vector` of `vector`s of size `STEP`, the last of these `vector`s shall have a smaller size if there were less than `STEP` elements remaining in the input container, let's call this partitioned container `bar`.

**I don't want to iterate over my input or output range multiple times.** The element of the problem I'm trying to solve are simply:

1. Append `bar` with a constructed `vector` of size `min(STEP, distance(it, foo.end())`
2. Have the `it` point to `advance(it, size(bar.back()))` after constructing the container
3. Do this `vector` construction in-place

The translation of my answer to the confines of this problem is:

```
auto it = cbegin(foo);

for (auto i = size(foo); i > STEP; i -= STEP) {
    bar.push_back(decltype(bar)::value_type(STEP));
    for (auto internalIt = bar.back().begin(); internalIt != bar.back().end(); ++internalIt, ++it) {
        *internalIt = *it;
    }
}
bar.push_back(decltype(bar)::value_type(it, cend(foo)));
```

The problem is this line: `bar.push_back(decltype(bar)::value_type(STEP))` I'm allocating the `vector` and 0-initializing it's components. Is there a better way to do this, under which I still would only iterate over the input and output ranges once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bar.push_back(decltype(bar)::value_type{}); // or bar.resize(bar.size() + 1); if you prefer
bar.back().reserve(STEP);
while (bar.back().size() < STEP) {
    bar.back().push_back(*it);
    ++it;
}
```

It's a stroke of bad luck that `std::copy_n` returns the advanced *output* iterator, when what you need to keep is the advanced *input* iterator, otherwise you could use that in place of the loop (using `std::back_inserter` to get the destination iterator).

Feel free to use a counter variable if you're concerned about the performance of `bar.back().size()`!

Comment: LOL, I actually had `copy_n` in my code and couldn't figure out why my input iterator wasn't getting advanced till I looked at it and realized it took the iterator by value. Anyway, you're suggesting that, an empty construction, allocation of space, and a `back_inserter` are better than construction with space allocated and direct assignment?

Comment: OK, so I've benchmarked it and can confirm that construct, allocate, and insert is always slower than construct with allocation and assign: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/206b8278ff67817f By the way, I don't know what's up with Coliru, but I don't trust it's results because they are always in 10,000 increments. But if you copy this and run locally you can confirm my assessment.

Comment: @JonathanMee: it's "better" only in the sense you asked for, that it only runs over each sub-vector of the results vector `bar` once, whereas your code runs over it twice (once to zero-initialize and once to assign). I didn't even consider whether it has better or worse runtime on any particular `vector` implementation, my remark about the performance of `bar.back().size()` was just an afterthought. With a sufficiently atrocious memory cache, such that the cost of a cache miss is truly exorbitant, and a big enough `STEP` to blow cache, we could arrange for this to run faster than your code ;-)

Comment: You're suggesting that if the vector that was allocated was large enough to cause a cache miss, my code would be more expensive because it must iterate through, 0 initializing the values, then it must iterate through assigning the values? I don't think that's the case. The compiler is smart enough to know that I'm doing a `calloc` and request 0 initialized memory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2688522/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee: depending on `value_type` it might not be a calloc (because it might not actually be zero initialization although I've called it that). But fair enough.

Comment: And I guess now that I'm thinking about it, `STEP` is constant. I'd really expect the compiler to roll this into initialization, perhaps it's just not smart enough to?