# Fast strlen function vs aliasing rules

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, strlen, strict-aliasing

I found [this](https://www.strchr.com/optimized_strlen_function) "fast strlen function" implementation:

```
// for x86 only
size_t my_strlen(const char *s) {
    size_t len = 0;
    for(;;) {
        unsigned x = *(unsigned*)s;
        if((x & 0xFF) == 0) return len;
        if((x & 0xFF00) == 0) return len + 1;
        if((x & 0xFF0000) == 0) return len + 2;
        if((x & 0xFF000000) == 0) return len + 3;
        s += 4, len += 4;
    }
}
```

An optimization techique used here is obviously simple: read memory by natural CPU words (the code is old and assumes x32 CPU), rather then by simple bytes.

But this code is violating aliasing rules, and so cause undefined behaviour, which can be freely optimized out by the compiler (those making code even faster, but inccorect).

I also see now that it is not portable, as it tied to the little-endian endianness.

Or may be i am completly wrong here and the code above is correct? Is it correct for C? For C++?

Comment: It does violate the rule. But have you tried to benchmark it? I am pretty sure the compiler will do better job optimizing the standard `strlen`.

Comment: It also violates alignment.

Comment: [OT] If you use a `std::string` instead of a `char*` the `size` function is O(1) which is hard to beat :)

Comment: @NathanOliver It's ironic in some ways that we're advocating `string` over C-String for the purposes of speed :J

Comment: @JonathanMee It really depends what the OP is using the strings for.  If they are static then I feel c-strings are fine.  If I do any string manipulation I stick with `std::string` as I hate doing manual memory management.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thank you, but i am already OK with the strings, as i am using my own [StaticallyBufferedString](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1038545/High-Performance-Statically-Buffered-String). The question was about code correctness.

Comment: @NathanOliver I strongly agree with your statement.

Comment: If you're considering this you'll want to note the requirements that I posted as part of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38080862/2642059) 1) You'd have to allocate `sizeof(unsigned) - 1` chars on the end of every string to use this. 2) The cost of requiring 2 load operations because `x` is unaligned will outweigh any cost savings 3) You'd have to templatize this function based on `sizeof(unsigned)` to make it portable. It's worth pointing out that [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) will remove   many of the motivations for immutable strings.

Comment: @JonathanMee: For efficiency, the code should process single bytes until it has an aligned pointer.  If that is done and an implementation is coded such that fetches which go beyond the end of an array but are within an allocated segment will, at worst, yield non-contagious indeterminate data [i.e. each read of the storage will yield a potentially-different value, but the values read will behave as normal values], then the array overreach wouldn't be a problem on platforms where memory segments must contain whole numbers of words [which is true on all implementations I know of].

Comment: @supercat That code would still not be defined by the C++ standard: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36425393/2642059 (Probably because as you say an operating system is not required to segment the memory based on memory layout.) But like you I don't know of any OS that behaves like that. So I believe in-spite of being undefined, if the extra steps are taken to ensure that `x` will be aligned the program will be well behaved.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I wish compiler writers would value the efficiency with which compilers can generate code *to perform various tasks* beyond the efficiency with which they can generate code *to generate the minimal Standard-mandated behavior for a particular piece of source text*, and recognize that regarding as defined constructs which might be expensive to support on some platforms, but not for the target, can make it possible to perform many tasks much more efficiently on common platforms.

Comment: @JonathanMee: If a programmer knows that the execution platform will behave sensibly in a case not mandated by the Standard, even if the compiler can't know that, a compiler for a low-level language should allow a programmer to exploit that knowledge.  I would suggest that a compiler which doesn't isn't really processing a low-level language.

Comment: @supercat We're talking about different things here. You're talking about the way a compiler generates code for a platform. But the question is asking about the programmer's ability to write code to direct the compiler to do things that may be illegal on some platforms. C++ defines the input language, the generated code can take whatever form the compiler wants.

Comment: @supercat The compiler *is* allowing that here, this is C/C++ after all we can do all kinds of magic with pointers. But this particular magic is not considered defined behavior under the standard. (Which is why we get the seg fault)

Comment: @JonathanMee: Over the last decade, compilers have become very aggressive at deciding that if the authors of the Standard refrained from mandating behavior in a given situation because *some* execution platforms might behave unpredictably, that should be taken as license to behave unpredictably *even on platforms where behavior would otherwise be defined*.  In many cases one may know enough about an execution platform to know that a straightforward translation of code won't trigger a seg-fault, but code may still fail anyway due to compiler "creativity".

Comment: @supercat I'd use this example to disprove your statement, as the compiler *is* allowing the user to code outside what the language allows. But I'm sure you're thinking of a different example? Perhaps you'd care to share?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Common practice in both C and Unix used to be that if an undocumented aspect of an interface's behavior turns out to be useful, it should become part of the API.  The authors of gcc seem to take the opposite attitude--they regard code which relies upon anything not mandated by the Standard as "broken" without regard for whether there would be any Standard-defined means of accomplishing the same task as cleanly and efficiently, or whether supporting the behavior in question would have any significant cost.

Comment: @JonathanMee: As a consequence, I don't regard gcc as really "allowing" the programmer to do anything unless the behavior is so rigidly documented that the authors of gcc won't be able to claim they never had any obligation to support it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115997/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-supercat).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just very bad code. Even the code's author warns:

- This function will crash if an non-readable memory page is located right after the end of the string. **The simplest way to prevent this is to allocate 3 additional bytes at the end of string.**
- The dwords may be unaligned, but x86 architecture allows access to unaligned data. For small strings, **the alignment will take more time than the penalty of unaligned reads**.
- **The code is not portable**: you will have to add another 4 conditions if you use a 64-bit processor. For big-endian architectures, the order of conditions should be reversed.

Even if this did not break the aliasing rule the burden placed on the coder to make `my_strlen` work is completely unjustifiable. It has been stated several times that `strlen` will already be tuned beyond anything the average coder could accomplish.

But an additional statement should be made for C++: [Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) in the [last page of chapter 4 in his book](https://books.google.com/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false): "The C++ Programming Language"  says:

> Prefer `strings` over C-style strings

You'll find taking the size of a `string` far more performant than finding the size of a C-String.

**EDIT:**

In [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080328/fast-strlen-function-vs-aliasing-rules/38080862?noredirect=1#comment63598463_38080328) you say you are working with [StaticallyBufferedString](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1038545/High-Performance-Statically-Buffered-String) which purports to solve `string`'s "pooling memory model" which causes:

- Unnecessary heap locks in a multithreaded context
- Fragmentation from real-time size control

I'd like to suggest C++17's [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) which like all of C++17 was constructed with multi-threading in mind. It provides the functionality of a `string` backed by heap and `constexpr` friendly C-Strings. You can even get a jump start on learning about it with `namespace experimental`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view Unlike your time put in on StaticallyBufferedStrings the knowledge you gain will be perfectly portable and applicable to any future C++ work you do!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! ALL of us, through, had written some bad and even very bad code, for which we should be ashamed, so i wouldn't judge the author too heavy ;)

Comment: @AmaboCarab You make a fair point. If you look at my question history on here I have demonstrated more than a few misunderstandings that have made their way into old code I've written. So I've edited to remove my caustic comments that were directed at the author.

Comment: a wise decision indeed. The ability to understand our faults, to admit and to correct them, to learn from our mistakes, is that what actually separtes the smart people from the foolish one :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad idea, and will make your performance worse. The standard `strlen` function provided by modern compilers is already highly optimized, and will do a much better job than above. For example, on SSE-enabled CPUs (i.e. pretty much all of them) it will already use SSE/AVX instructions to do a vectorized search for the null terminator, and will consider more than 4 bytes at a time as above with fewer comparison-related instructions, and fewer branches that can be mis-predicted.

Comment: From the webpage: **This article should be viewed as an exercise in code optimization, not as a recommendation for everyday programming.** It's optimized compared to the naive C implementation of `strlen()`, not the one built into the library.

Comment: @Smeeheey, you are absolutly correct, yes, of course, the modern compiler will just use bulltin intrinsic (if it is enabled by the compiler options), but the question was about code correctness, because, as i see it now, it violates aliasing, alignment and endianess.

Comment: @Smeeheey i also doesn't understand how the branches in this code can be misspredicted, as the whole function's code is so small, that it fits even L1 cache many times.

Comment: Instruction caching and branch mis-prediction are two entirely separate concepts. Due to the pipeline, a CPU has to guess where to go after each branch (5 in your case - the four `if`s plus the `for`), and if its gets it wrong it has to flush the pipeline which is an expensive operation. This is irrespective of whether the code is in the cache or not. See [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-the-cost-of-branch-misprediction) for more

Comment: @Smeeheey, thank you for the clarification, my shame that i completly forgot about the mordern CPU pipeline.

Comment: If a standard-library function fits one's needs, it's probably going to be faster than a custom implementation.  But suppose e.g. that one has strings which are terminated by dollar signs rather than zero bytes [a format used in I think CP/M].  Code which starts by comparing as many individual characters as are needed to fix the alignment and then processes words after that could outpace code which has to read all characters individually.

Comment: Even in cases where one needs to find the first zero, however, that wouldn't imply that the standard library function is optimal, since the optimal function to find the first zero in string which is likely to be long will perform badly on short strings, and the optimal function to find the first zero in strings that are likely to be short will perform badly on long ones.  If the Standard had different names for "strlen optimized for short strings" and "strlen optimized for long strings" [which implementations could treat as synonymous or distinct at their leisure] then...

Comment: ...code which used the version appropriate to the probable lengths of strings it was using could expect a modern library to implement it well.  Absent such a distinction, I would expect many library versions are optimized for short strings rather than long ones, and a chunking version could achieve a massive speedup on longer strings.

Answer (score 1):

The function as written is neither optimal nor portable.  That having been said, the authors of C89 included some badly-written rules which if interpreted strictly make C89 a much less powerful language than the earlier C dialects that existed on many platforms.  The stated purpose of the rule is to avoid requiring a C compilers which given code like:

```
float *fp;
int i;

int foo(void)
{
  i++;
  *fp=1.0f;
  return i;
}
```

from having to pessimistically assume that the write to `*fp` might affect `i` *despite the complete absence of anything that would suggest that something of type `int` might be affected*.  Code which used type punning for a variety of purposes including chunking optimizations was widespread when C89 was written, but most such code would have included clear indications to the compiler that aliasing was going to occur.  Generally, if an object was going to be modified by a foreign-type pointer between two "normal" accesses, one or both of the following would occur between the two normal accesses:

1. The object's address would be taken.
2. A pointer would be converted from the object's type to another type.

Aside from the obvious case where a pointer is used to access an object of
its precise type, the Standard mostly identifies cases where it would not be
obvious that a compiler should assume aliasing was possible (e.g. between
an "int" and a pointer of type "unsigned*", or between anything and a pointer
of type "char*").  Given the rationale, I think the authors intended to
focus on making sure that compiler writers handled the cases where there
would be no reason to expect aliasing, but didn't think they needed to be
told how to identify cases where it was obviously likely.

Chunking optimizations will be safe on compilers which recognize that the
address-of and casting operators imply that cross-type aliasing is likely,
provided that all use of the pointer resulting from a cast is performed
before the next access using the non-cast pointer--a requirement that most
chunking code would generally meet.  Unfortunately, there is no standard
for "sane-compiler C", and gcc uses the fact that the authors of the
Standard didn't require that compilers handle the obvious-aliasing cases as
justification to ignore them.

Still, the performance advantages from chunking optimizations may outweigh
the performance costs of `-fno-strict-aliasing`, especially if code uses
`restrict` qualifiers when appropriate.  There are some situations, mainly
involving global variables, where `restrict` isn't sufficient to enable
useful optimizations; those could be handled by an aliasing mode which limits
analysis to objects of static or automatic duration (like the objects in the
rationale's example) but gcc offers no such mode.

BTW, I'm not sure what instruction timings are like on modern x86 processors, but on some ARM variants compilers would have a chance at producing optimal long-string code from something like:

```
uint32_t x01000000 = 0x01000000;
uint64_t *search(uint64_t *p)
{
  uint64_t n;
  uint32_t a,b;
  uint32_t v = x01000000; // See note
  do
  {
    n=*p++;
    a=(uint32_t)n;
    b=n>>32;
    if (a >= v  || (a << 8) >= v || (a << 16) >= v || (a << 24) >= v ||
        b >= v  || (b << 8) >= v || (b << 16) >= v || (b << 24) >= v) return p;
  } while(1);      
}
```

Figuring out which comparison was responsible for breaking out of the loop would take extra time, but keeping such considerations out of the loop may allow the loop itself to be more efficient.

Many ARM processors have an instruction which can compare a shifted value with a register; compilers sometimes need a little help to realize that 0x01000000 should be kept in a register (a compare-with-constant instruction exists, but
doesn't include a "free" shift of the register being compared), but with help they can find the compare-with-shift.  I haven't yet found a way to convince a compiler to generate optimal code for the ARM7-TDMI, which would be equivalent to:

```
search:
    mov    r1,#0x010000000
lp:
    ldrmia r0,{r2,r3}
    cmp    r1,r2
    cmplt  r1,r2,asl #8
    cmplt  r1,r2,asl #16
    cmplt  r1,r2,asl #24
    cmplt  r1,r3
    cmplt  r1,r3,asl #8
    cmplt  r1,r3,asl #16
    cmplt  r1,r3,asl #24
    blt    lp
    bx     lr
```

That would take 15 cycles per eight bytes; it could be adapted to take 25 cycles per sixteen bytes.  A loop that processes eight bytes individually would take 42 cycles; unrolled to sixteen bytes would be 82 cycles.  The best loop I've seen compilers generate for the uint64_t based code would be 22 cycles for eight bytes--almost half again as long as the optimal code, but still about twice as fast as a version using bytes.